# Installing redis 5.x package in virtualenv without pip

Tags: python, redis, pip, virtualenv

I installed `redis 3.5.3` using `pip` in a virtualenv. But as I needed `redis 5.x`, I uninstalled redis and tried to use newer version using `pip`. But, I got

```sh
$ pip install redis==5.0.5
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement redis==5.0.5 (from versions: 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 1.34, 1.34.1, 2.0.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.2, 2.2.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9, 2.4.10, 2.4.11, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.7.5, 2.7.6, 2.8.0, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.10.2, 2.10.3, 2.10.5, 2.10.6, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.post1, 3.0.1, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.3.4, 3.3.5, 3.3.6, 3.3.7, 3.3.8, 3.3.9, 3.3.10, 3.3.11, 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.5.2, 3.5.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for redis==5.0.5
```

So, I resorted to installing it using make.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ cd redis-5.0.5
$ make
```

and run the server using `$ src/redis-server`. To which I get

```
...lots of verbose...
14126:M 22 Jun 2020 12:15:30.196 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
14126:M 22 Jun 2020 12:15:30.196 * Ready to accept connections
14126:M 22 Jun 2020 12:15:41.798 * DB saved on disk
```

I suppose the the package got installed globally and the redis-server is running (also verified using `sudo systemctl status redis`). But, now when I again use my virtualenv and `import redis`, I get the missing package error.

How should I use redis 5.x in my virtualenv python script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.5.tar.gz point to Redis (the database) executable.

That is the first step to get Redis working with Python,

The second step is to get the Python's Redis package to connect to the database.

Since the Python's Redis package isn't the same thing than the actual Redis database, you don't need to get the version of the package matching with the version of your database, all you should need is:

```
pip install redis
```

To get the last version of the Python's Redis package.

From there, with your database running in background, you can connect using Python with:

```
import redis
db = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, [...])
```

Comment: Thanks for __Since the Python's Redis package isn't the same thing than the actual Redis database, you don't need to get the version of the package matching with the version of your database__